# Combinatorial method for fundamental group

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I recall learning a "combinatorial" method for computing fundamental group of simplicial complexes (not graphs) involving maximal tree.

It is something like this: a group is generated by generators $g_{ab}$, where $ab$ is a 1-simplex of the simplicial complex $K$ not in the maximal tree $A$, subject to certain relations.

However I forget some details and would like to consult a reference. Is there any reference containing information on the above?

Comment: Armstrong's Basic Topology book.

Comment: I'm no expert, but you could check out Wu's paper https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.gt/1513732523 and its references. Also https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.3055 .

Comment: Here is something really similiar to what you describe, but for computing the fundamental group of posets, a.k.a. finite $T_0$ topological spaces (see theorem 4.4) https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.6442